# GDB breakpoint not hit

Tags: c++, gdb, g++

I am trying to debug C++ code. But when I set a breakpoint at the line "break;", the breakpoint cannot be hit. I am using MinGW64 to compile C++ code with `-g` flag on Windows, and without any optimization flags.

A short code to reproduce the problem:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <random>
using namespace std;

static default_random_engine generator(0); //random seed
static normal_distribution<double> normal;
static uniform_real_distribution<double> uniform;
static exponential_distribution<double> expo; 


int main() {
    int k_max = round(uniform(generator)*100+3);
    double c = 0;
    for (int k=0;k<k_max;k++) {
        double a = expo(generator);
        double b = normal(generator);

        if ( a*b<a+b) { 
            c *= 1.5;
            if (sqrt(a+1) < 0.7) {
                c += 2*expo(generator);
            } else if (sqrt(a+2)>2.9) {
                c += 3*expo(generator);
            } else {
                c += expo(generator);
            }
            //std::cout<<"Before break"<<std::endl;
            break; // Where the breakpoint is set
        }
    }
    cout << c << endl;
}
```

**What I have tried:**

I disassembled the code before and after the breakpoint and saw something like that:

```
25                  } else {
26                      c += expo(generator);
   0x0000000140001606 <+438>:   lea    0x6a37(%rip),%rax        # 0x140008044 <_ZL9generator>
   0x000000014000160d <+445>:   mov    %rax,%rdx
   0x0000000140001610 <+448>:   lea    0x6a79(%rip),%rax        # 0x140008090 <_ZL4expo>
   0x0000000140001617 <+455>:   mov    %rax,%rcx
   0x000000014000161a <+458>:   call   0x140003180 <_ZNSt24exponential_distributionIdEclISt26linear_congruential_engineIjLj16807ELj0ELj2147483647EEEEdRT_>
   0x000000014000161f <+463>:   movsd  -0x8(%rbp),%xmm1
   0x0000000140001624 <+468>:   addsd  %xmm1,%xmm0
   0x0000000140001628 <+472>:   movsd  %xmm0,-0x8(%rbp)

27                  }
28                  //std::cout<<"Before break"<<std::endl;
29                  break;
   0x0000000140001593 <+323>:   jmp    0x14000163f <main()+495>
   0x0000000140001604 <+436>:   jmp    0x14000163f <main()+495>
   0x000000014000162d <+477>:   jmp    0x14000163f <main()+495>

30              }
```

So I wonder if the GDB debugger only insert `INT 3` into one of the jump commands. If so, how can I ensure that the breakpoint is not skipped? (i.e. change the compilation flags.) Or, did I do something wrong when compiling and debugging?

Comment: I'm not sure there is a compilation flag that does what you want. I'm guessing it worked when you uncommented the `std::cout<<"Before break"<<std::endl;` line.

Comment: But you do bring up a good point. Since the 3 `jmp` instructions you mentioned have the correct line information, may gdb **should** put breakpoints on all 3 locations. But maybe then you would get too many breakpoints when optimizations are enabled, since usually this would move around the instructions a lot.